# How shutdown KafkaListener when error occurs

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I wrote a Listener in this way

```java
@Autowired
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

@KafkaListener(containerFactory = "cdcKafkaListenerContainerFactory", errorHandler = "errorHandler")
public void consume(@Payload String message) throws Exception {
    ...
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerErrorHandler errorHandler() {
    return ((message, e) -> {
        kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop();
        return null;
    });
}
```

In `@KafkaListener` annotation I specified my error handler that simply stop the consumer.
It seems to work but I've some question to ask.

Is there a built-in errorHandler for this scope? I've read that `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler` can be use, but I cannot set it because `@KafkaListener`'s errorHandler accept beans of `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` type.

I see that with `kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop()`; do a graceful stop. So before stopping the partition offset of the consumed message is committed.
What I would know is what happen when `kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop();` is called and before listener is definitely turned off another message arrive into the topic?
Is this message consumed?

I image this scenario

```
time0: kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop() is called
time1: a message is pushed into the listened topic
time2: kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop() complete graceful stop
```

I'm worried about a possible message arrive at time1. What would happen in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not stop the container within the listener.

`ContainerStoppingErrorHandler` is set on the container factory, not the annotation.

If you are using Spring Boot, just declare the error handler as a bean and boot will wire it in.

Otherwise add the error handler to the connection factory bean.

With this error handler, throwing an exception will immediately stop the container.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I added `factory.setErrorHandler(new ContainerStoppingErrorHandler());` into kafka listener container factory.
In this way I should be safe?